# In CQS is it accepted to have a coupling to another command

Tags: c#, coupling, cqs

Consider this code, rather than hardcoding the hour when we execute a certain command I query the CQS engine and asks when it will be executed. Though now we have a high coupling to another command. You consider this ok?

```
public class CancelInvoiceCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CancelInvoiceCommand>
{
    private readonly IInvoiceRepository _invoiceRepository;
    private readonly IPaymentRepository _paymentRepository;
    private readonly IBankDayService _bankDayService;
    private readonly ICommandScheduler _commandScheduler;

    public CancelInvoiceCommandHandler(IInvoiceRepository invoiceRepository, IPaymentRepository paymentRepository, IBankDayService bankDayService, ICommandScheduler commandScheduler)
    {
        _invoiceRepository = invoiceRepository;
        _paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
        _bankDayService = bankDayService;
        _commandScheduler = commandScheduler;
    }

    public async Task Handle(CancelInvoiceCommand command)
    {
        var invoice = await _invoiceRepository.GetByAsync(command.InvoiceId);
        var autogiroPayment = invoice.ActivePayments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PaymentType == PaymentType.Autogiro);
        
        if(invoice.InvoiceType == InvoiceType.ProviderInvoice) throw new ArgumentException("Not allowed to cancel provider invoice");
        if(invoice.ActivePayments.Any(p => p != autogiroPayment)) throw new ArgumentException("Invoice have registered payments");

        if (autogiroPayment != null)
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var latestHourToCancel = _commandScheduler.GetNextExecutionTime<SendPendingAutogiroWithdrawalCancellationsCommand>().Hour;

            var daysUntilDueDate = await _bankDayService.BankDaysBetweenAsync(now.Date, invoice.DueDate);
            var canCancelAutogiroPayment = daysUntilDueDate > 2 || daysUntilDueDate == 2 && now.Hour < latestHourToCancel;
            if (!canCancelAutogiroPayment) throw new ArgumentException("Less than one bank day until invoice due date");

            await _paymentRepository.UpdateStateAsync(autogiroPayment, PaymentState.PendingCancellation);
        }

        await _invoiceRepository.UpdateStateAsync(invoice.InvoiceId, InvoiceState.Canceld, invoice.UpdatedUTC);
        await _invoiceRepository.ResetParentAsync(invoice.InvoiceId);
        await _invoiceRepository.DeleteChildrenAsync(invoice.InvoiceId, command.DeletedChildren.NullSafe().ToList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scheduled commands?

"Get next execution time" sounds more like a scheduled task than a command in the CQS sense. Of course, such a job could just call a single command, but that doesn't mean they aren't two separate concepts.

I think the distinction between scheduled job and command is important here, as we're dealing with a question about good practice as opposed to technical viability.

In short, if we're talking about a scheduled job, it's perfectly fine to look up information regarding this job and based your algorithm off of that. This remains true whether we're talking about commands in CQS or any other piece of business logic.

But I would advice you to separate the command from the jobs. If not technically, then at the very least semantically. The way things are named now, your commands are not really CQS commands, and I can only infer from the question that you're looking for some clean adherence to CQS.

That being said, you also mention "the CQS engine", which makes me wonder if you're using a premade library to route (and schedule) your commands. If so, then the semantical argument I'm making here is moot, as you're going to be bound by the semantics of the library you're working with.

Whether you should wrap those (IMO badly named) library semantics into your own custom (IMO cleaner) semantics, is a matter of effort for the sake of readability.

---

### Daisy-chaining?

> I guess if its ok to chain other commands from a command handler this is ok too?

While the context of my linked reference here is Mediatr-oriented (as opposed to only CQS), [I once asked pretty much the same question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/iftjez/mediatr_chain_requests_for_reusable_subtasks/). There were a lot of good answers written there, which I suggest you read if you want context and anecdotal experiences.

The conclusion is that it's perfectly viable from a technical perspective, but it's less desirable from a design perspective. The CQS pattern's main drive is to avoid a web of connections, instead favoring a flat list of individual distinct commands (and queries). By daisy-chaining them, you are recreating that web, albeit with baby steps.

The better approach here is to put the shared logic (i.e. any logic that does not uniquely belong to a single command) and put it in a service class, which can then be injected into your commands. This enables multiple commands to rely on a reusable piece of logic, without having to tie the commands themselves together.

Comment: I have developed our own cqs engine. It's pretty simple, you can execute commands in 3 ways. In memory directly, queue them on bus and shedule them. We also support that you queue commands from a command. These will be executed after the current command is exeuted. Our commands have a bit of domain specifics built into them. For example they are by convention unit of work and they do not commit their changes until after the command have executed. Etc

Comment: About chaining commands we do it for stuff like communicate state to other systems etc. This way the main command will execute and commit its business logic. If the command that communicates states fails you can rerun it, open a support ticket on it etc. We have found this to work very well.

Comment: @Anders: Like I said, it works on a technical level, so it will do what you need it to do. However, part of good practice is a matter of principle, intent, and generalized advice (i.e. not based on your specific requirements, but rather global development convention). Whether you adhere to the generalized advice is a matter of whether you want to, and whether you may have specific requirements that conflict with it.